# What contenteditable editors are there?

Tags: contenteditable

This question should serve as a listing of all the different content-editable solutions. Post new ones in the answers below.

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_rich-text_editor

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/149978) answer. You can [edit me](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6756414/edit) with your improvements. Alphabetically sorted.

### Inline

Inline editors differ from normal editors as they can edit the content directly, i.e. not placing it inside another element, or inside an iframe.

- <s>[Aloha Editor](http://aloha-editor.org/)</s> inactive since May 2016
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) - starting from [CKEditor 4 Beta](http://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-4-beta)
- [Etch](http://etchjs.com/)
- <s>[FresherEditor](https://github.com/mquan/freshereditor)</s> inactive since November 2012
- [Hallo](https://github.com/bergie/hallo)
- <s>[HTML5 Edit](https://github.com/balupton/html5edit)</s> inactive since July 2011
- <s>[Mercury](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/)</s> inactive since December 2013
- [NicEdit](http://nicedit.com/)
- [Quill](http://quilljs.com/) - starting from v0.19
- [RedactorJS](http://imperavi.com/redactor/)
- [TinyMCE when used with Inline mode](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/inline.php)
- [wysiwyg.js](http://wysiwygjs.github.io/)
- [medium.js](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/) (library independent)
- [ContentTools](http://getcontenttools.com/) (Library independent)
- [Froala WYSIWYG](https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) (jQuery)
- [Trix](https://github.com/basecamp/trix)
- [Trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/) (jQuery)
- [editable.js](https://github.com/upfrontIO/editable.js)
- [wysihtml](https://github.com/Voog/wysihtml)

### Iframes

Iframe editors often load the editor or content to edit into an iframe, to avoid styling conflicts.

- [bootstrap-wysihtml5](http://jhollingworth.github.com/bootstrap-wysihtml5/)
- [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)
- <s>[Mercury](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/)</s> inactive since December 2013
- [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)
- <s>[WYSIHTML5](http://xing.github.com/wysihtml5/)</s> inactive since December 2014

Comment: https://github.com/JefMari/awesome-wysiwyg-editors

Answer (score 9):

***Javascript contenteditable WYSIWYG editors list***

**Lightweight versions**

- PunyMCE, from the authors of TinyMCE http://github.com/spocke/punymce
- NicEdit http://nicedit.com/
- WysiHat (Prototype) http://github.com/37signals/wysihat/
- widgEditor http://code.google.com/p/widgeditor/
- WYMeditor (jQuery) http://www.wymeditor.org/
- jWYSIWYG (jQuery) http://code.google.com/p/jwysiwyg/
- ggEdit (MooTools) http://code.google.com/p/ggedit/
- YUI Rich Text Editor – SimpleEditor (YUI) http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/
- uEditor (jQuery) http://www.upian.com/upiansource/ueditor/en/
- Loki http://code.google.com/p/loki-editor/
- MooRTE (MooTools) http://github.com/siteroller/moorte/
- WMD – Markdown Editor http://wmd-editor.com/
- goog.editor (Closure Library) http://code.google.com/p/closure-library/
- (demo) lwrte (jQuery) http://lwrte.googlecode.com/
- wkrte (jQuery) http://wkrte.googlecode.com/
- jHtmlArea (jQuery) http://jhtmlarea.codeplex.com/
- TinyEditor (jQuery) http://www.leigeber.com/2010/02/javascript-wysiwyg-editor/
- dijit.Editor (Dojo) http://www.dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/Editor.html
- CLEditor (jQuery) http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/
- wysihtml5 https://github.com/xing/
- WYSIWYG (jQuery) http://maccman.github.com/wysiwyg/
- Redactor (jQuery) http://redactorjs.com/
- SimpleHtml5Editor (ZeptoJs and coffeescript): https://github.com/TheOtherNet/simpleHtml5Editor/
- bootstrap-wysiwyg (jQuery) https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/
- https://github.com/cheeaun/mooeditable

**Heavyweights**

- Aloha Editor http://aloha-editor.com/
- TinyMCE http://www.tinymce.com/
- CKEditor http://ckeditor.com/
- YUI Rich Text Editor – Editor (YUI) http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/editor/
- elRTE (jQuery UI) http://elrte.org
- Mercury Editor (jQuery, CoffeeScript, Rails) http://jejacks0n.github.com/mercury/

Comment: https://github.com/JefMari/awesome-wysiwyg-editors