# ckeditor - edit contenteditable div outside editor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have div with my ckeditor (only toolbar):

```
editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo('topSpace',
{
    editingBlock: false
});
```

and I want to edit text in my contenteditable div, but buttons in toolbar don't work for selected text. Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

CKEditor uses iframe for editing, which is different from making on-page divs editable via contenteditable. Fortunately there are some contenteditable editors out there for you:

- [Aloha](http://aloha-editor.org/)
- [Hallo](https://github.com/bergie/hallo)
- [Mercury](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury)

More from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6756414/232288

Comment: Iframe is only one of options in CKEditor. Using it with contenteditable divs is very easy and there's no need to recommend using another editor.