# What backend-agnostic admin interfaces / GUIs are there?

Tags: user-interface

This question should serve as a listing of all the different backend-agnostic admin interfaces. [Update the community wiki answer below to add more.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18575346/edit)

Comment: I believe this question is on topic because it covers "software tools commonly used by programmers". We use admin interfaces everyday, and we need a community managed listing of all the backend-agnostic ones. In the exact same way how we [needed a listing of what contenteditable editors there are](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6756407/130638), another ontopic and similar question.

Comment: This question is of topic because it is a product recommendation list. So is the one you linked.

Comment: Where does it say such things are not allowed? Where should such things go? What about the value such questions bring?

Comment: @balupton - there is a specific close reason for the type of question you are asking: *"**Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool**, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow..."* See also the helper center: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: That's lame, but fair enough, thanks for bringing that to my attention. Luckily, once it is closed, that will prevent new answers (stopping spam) but still allow people with enough rep to edit the community wiki answer (allowing the benefits while stopping spam), everybody wins right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) answer. You should [edit me](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18575346/edit) with your improvements. Alphabetically sorted.

### Implementations

- **[AdminJS](https://web.archive.org/web/20141216185216/http://adminjs.com/) is a database table like GUI with CRUD abilities**

  NOTE: No longer maintained.

  [image: AdminJS Listing Screenshot]
  <sub>(source: [webresourcesdepot.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20171010232243/http://webresourcesdepot.com/wp-content/uploads/adminjs.gif))</sub>
- **[Create.js](https://www.createjs.org/) is an inline editing GUI for editing content and managing collections, it provides a widget interface and can be extended to have WYSIWYG editors placed ontop of it**

  [image: Create.js running with Aloha Editor]
  <sub>(source: [bergie.iki.fi](http://bergie.iki.fi/files/1e04599abfee694459911e0bf1021b4fddbed1bed1b_midgardcreate-save-transition-small.png))</sub>
- **[HydraConsole](https://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/) is a generic API console for Hydra-powered Web APIs.**

  [image: HydraConsole]
- **[Lumber](https://github.com/ForestAdmin/lumber) Lumber uses your SQL or MongoDB database to generates a modern Admin Interface application that is completely backend agnostic and highly flexible.**

  [image: Lumber]

- **[ng-admin](https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin): Add an AngularJS admin GUI to any RESTful API**

  [image: ng-admin screenshot]
- **[Web Write's InlineGUI](https://github.com/bevry-archive/inlinegui) is an inline editing GUI with CRUD and site management abilities**

  [image: WebWrite Edit Page Screenshot]

### Specs/Frameworks

- [Create.js Backend Integration Guide](http://www.createjs.org/guide/#communications_with_the_cms_backend) - REST API spec for CRUD actions
- [VIE](http://viejs.org/) - server-agnostic JavaScript data layer built on the W3C RDFa and JSON-LD specs and used in Create.js
- [Hydra](https://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/core/) - a lightweight vocabulary to create hypermedia-driven Web APIs. By specifying a number of concepts commonly used in Web APIs it enables the creation of generic API clients.
- [Web Write Spec](https://github.com/bevry-archive/webwrite) - REST API spec for CRUD actions and collection listings
- [Neutron Protocol](https://web.archive.org/web/20121115094012/http://neutron.wyona.org:80/) - XML and WebDAV protocol for content editing
- [The Atom Publishing Protocol](https://bitworking.org/projects/atom/rfc5023/) - XML and WebDAV protocol for content editing
- [MetaWeblog API](https://codex.wordpress.org/XML-RPC_MetaWeblog_API) - XML-RPC API for blog-oriented content editing
- [Data.js](https://web.archive.org/web/20131127222200/http://interior.substance.io:80/modules/data.html) - data representation framework for Javascript
- [Twingle](https://web.archive.org/web/20190718164514/http://twingle.mozdev.org/) - XUL application and protocol for cross-system content editing (discontinued)

### Articles

- [Moving DocPad Forward, the rise of backend-agnostic GUIs](https://gist.github.com/balupton/2906284)
- [Decoupling Content Management](https://bergie.iki.fi/blog/decoupling_content_management/)
- [VIE 2.0 is starting to emerge](https://bergie.iki.fi/blog/vie_2-0_is_starting_to_emerge/)
- [Using RDFa to make web pages editable](https://bergie.iki.fi/blog/using_rdfa_to_make_a_web_page_editable/)
- [Neutrol Protocol - separating UI from the CMS](https://bergie.iki.fi/blog/neutron_protocol-separating_ui_from_the_cms/)
- [ng-admin: Add an AngularJS admin GUI to any RESTful API](https://marmelab.com/blog/2014/09/15/easy-backend-for-your-restful-api.html)

Comment: I've added an articles section while this philosophy is still new to serve as an introduction to what backend-agnostic GUIs are and as they develop. Once backend-agnostic GUIs have matured a bit and become more commonplace, it could be a good time to retract the articles section.

Answer (score 3):

There is also https://github.com/punkave/jquery-rest-admin
In this context http://jsonapi.org could also start playing a role.

Comment: The other answer is publicly editable, so you could actually include this in the list there :-)