# Data Management / CRUD Generator AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, templates, user-interface, crud

I am looking for a simple CRUD template system for AngularJS that dynamically creates UIs to manage entities via REST. Is there something out there that does this already or a template that is easy to adjust?

Ideally a framework / template where all I have to do is specify a REST resource layout, and a data model definition in JSON that describes entities and relations.

Any recommendations? I don't want to build this again in another language =)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should try **Telosys** http://www.telosys.org/

See all the tutorials https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/
and especially the tutorial dedicated to **AngularJS** https://sites.google.com/site/telosystutorial/angularjs

Answer (score 0):

**mCrud**

Somebody created a Node.js / AngularJS application using material design to do generic crud on a MySQL database using sequalize as an orm. It looks good. You can purchase it for 27 USD.

Here it is:
https://codecanyon.net/item/mcrud-materialized-database-crud-generator/14617925

**ng-admin**

An AngularJS admin GUI to any RESTful API

https://github.com/marmelab/ng-admin

**and even more...**

There's a community wiki answer on the same topic.

[What backend-agnostic admin interfaces / GUIs are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18575345/what-backend-agnostic-admin-interfaces-guis-are-there)